# Происхождение слова "проблема".

Tags: этимология

Хотелось бы побольше узнать о происхождении слова **проблема**.

Answer (score 3):

Мне показалась убедительной этимология по Фасмеру:

Происходит от поздн. лат. problema, из греч. provlima «брошенное вперёд, поставленное впереди»; от provallo «кидать вперёд, выставлять перед собой; обвинять»; из pro + vallo. Русск. проблема — начиная с Петра I; заимств. Через польск. problema или стар. нем. Problema (с 1558 г.).

Обширную подборку множества спорных толкований можно посмотреть здесь:
http://www.proza.ru/2012/07/16/386